# Интерпретация множества в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, множества, set

Подскажите пожалуйста логику работы следующей строки:

```
{x for x in 'abcddeef' if x not in 'abc'}
```

Comment: Проходимся каждому символу строки `abcddeef` и проверяем есть ли он в строке `abc`. Если есть, то пропускаем, если же его нет, то записываем. `{}` означают сет, т.е. уникальные значения. Считайте, что у сет мы добавляем эти символы и если они повторяются, то просто пропускаем и не добавляем. В итоге выйдет `def`.

Comment: Я думал почему получается "def" а не "ddeef". Спасибо что напомнили что в set все значения уникальны, теперь понятно!